# Quando gero o Checkbox com o javascript ele não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Seguinte. Eu tenho um input select com Estados (Rj, SP, MS), Quando seleciono ele, ele faz uma busca via ajax ($.post) e me trás como resposta, em JSON, os dados das cidades (código, nome, uf, status) em uma lista com um checkbox + nome da cidade. Vou postar o código abaixo:

```
jQuery('#cidade_select').on('change', function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    var cidade_url = 'rota_cidades.php';
    if (data) {
        $.post(cidade_url, {
                cidade: data,
            },
            function(j) {
                var options = '<h4 class="text-center col-md-12 ml-3">Selecione a cidade para ativá-la no mapa da página <strong>"Localidades"</strong></h4>';
                var j = jQuery.parseJSON(j);
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<div class="col-md-4 mt-2">' +
                        '<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-control-success">' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cidade_' + j[i].cod_cidade + '" name="cidade_status" data-status="' + j[i].cod_cidade + '" ' + (j[i].status ? "checked" : "") + ' value="1" />' +
                        '<label class="custom-control-label" for="cidade_' + j[i].cod_cidade + '"><span class="d-none d-sm-inline-block"> (' + j[i].ddd + ')' + j[i].cidade + '-' + j[i].cidade_uf + ' </span></label>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                }
                $(".listar_cidades").html(options);
            }
        );
    } else {
        $(".listar_cidades").html('<h4 class="text-center py-5"> Selecione o Estado Primeiro. </h4>');
    }
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona certinho conforme a foto acima. Aparece todas as cidades com checkbox estilizado e etc. porém, ele não pega a ação de change do estado do elemento checkbox conforme o outro código:

```
 // Alterar Status
$('input[name="cidade_status"]').on('change', function() {

    var data = $(this).data();

    if (data.status > 0) {
        Iwas.helpers('notify', {
            type: 'success',
            icon: 'fa fa-check mr-1',
            message: 'Quase lá! Continuar testando'
        });
    } else {
        Iwas.helpers('notify', {
            type: 'danger',
            icon: 'fa fa-check mr-1',
            message: 'Ops! Algo deu errado. Fale com o desenvolvedor.'
        });
    }
});
```

Quando eu faço isso, por exemplo no HTML puro no código, ele funciona! Aparece a mensagem do notify, Só quando é gerado via javascript que não funciona. O que pode ser? O que estou fazendo de errado??

Já estou alguns dias analisando, testando e não cheguei na resposta ainda. Tenho o mesmo sistema em um outro site, porém, usando o Select/Option para popular bairros de uma cidade. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor??? :)

Comment: Ele não da nenhum erro no console? Quando você realizou o teste direto no HTML, como você fez? O código é exatamente igual e você colocou dentro da tag <script></script>?

Comment: Sim, é o mesmo código, tanto que, copiei de um funcional primeiro. Sempre faço primeiro o teste em html pra verificar espaçamentos e estilizações antes de passar para uma geração dinâmica, porém, não vai. Ele gera o elemento com espaçamento e estilização corretamente. O Elemento é clicável. porém, não gera erro, não dá mensagem alguma no console. Já tentei, pesquisei e não achei nada. Tá tenso! rsrs

Comment: Coloca um console.log dentro do seu onchange Jquery, logo após esse trecho: "$('input[name="cidade_status"]').on('change', function() {". Assim você vai saber se ele tá pegando o evento corretamente... Caso não esteja pegando o evento, pode ser a estrutura de arquivos js que você está usando, ou você não importou, sei lá.

Comment: Uma outra estratégia seria adicionar esse trecho em Jquery dentro de uma função e colocar essa função direto no html dinamicamente. Você já faz isso... Só precisaria adicionar a sua função no onchange do elemento. Mais ou menos assim: '<input type="checkbox" onchange=" ' + minhaFuncao() + ' " />' Lembre-se que ao adicionar o trecho do seu código direto em um evento no HTML, você não precisa mais dessa linha: "$('input[name="cidade_status"]').on('change', function() {"

Comment: Já tinha usado o console.log. Acho que até foi o primeiro que usei. Debug é tudo! Mas esse nem informa no debug. Simplesmente ele funciona a funçãode On/Off porém, não executa nada. O MESMO código, em html, sem ser dinâmico, funciona corretamente. Não sei... Vou acabar chamando dinamicamente via PHP mesmo pra testar. Vamos ver se resolve. Mesmo Assim, obrigado!